# Trouble iterating through an API with a list using Zenpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, zendesk

this might be a bit specific and I know it's related to the fact that my python training is all self taught. I'm trying to use a wrapper called [Zenpy](http://docs.facetoe.com.au/zenpy.html) to make some API calls for me. Specifically, I have a list of ticket ids. I'm trying to run a search for each ticket id, save the data into a variable, then print the variable (ultimately do a lot more with the data in the variable, but for my purposes they're the same). Trouble is my script is working, but I think it's failing to do the search. Here's my code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
creds = {
    'email': 'redacted',
    'token': 'redacted',
    'subdomain': 'redacted'

yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=20)
today = datetime.now()

from zenpy import Zenpy

zenpy = Zenpy(**creds)
print('Connected to Zendesk')

test_list = ['12345',
        '12346',
        '12347',
        '12348',
        '12349',
        '12350',
        '12351',
        '12352'
        ]

for ticket in zenpy.search(test_list):
    id = ticket.id
    print(id)
```

I imagine it's something to do with how the API is making the call and how its parsing a list (have also tried it as a dict and the results were the same) but no idea what to do. Have also tried zenpy.search(id=test_list) without any success.

Comment: Do the ZenPy docs say what type of argument `.search()` takes?  Will it take a list?  have you tried to get it to work with a single item from `test_list`, without the loop?

Comment: Well, that would just make too much sense. Got so caught up in it I didn't try it at its most basic. So if I have just a variable in .search it works perfectly. But if I use a list (even a list containing a single item) it gives me TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found. 
Any idea how to get around that kind of limitation?

Comment: If you pay attention to the error messages they usually give you a pretty good hint at the problem. That coupled with the successful test you did with a single string should make it clear.

Comment: FYI, the `tickets` endpoint will accept a list of ids: `zenpy_client.tickets(ids=[6151, 6152, 6153, 6154, 6155, 6156, 6157])`

Comment: Thanks much facetoe! Didn't even realize that was an option and thats probably much more efficient. Thanks a ton for zenpy, has made my life much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.search()` takes a single string for its search term.  Iterate over the list and make multiple searches.

```
for thing in test_list:
    ticket = zenpy.search(thing)
    id = ticket.id
    print(id)
```